# Difference between Client SSL and end to end SSL

Tags: security, ssl, https, web

We are asked to enable https for our website. While we contact our infrastructure team, they were asking which kind of SSL is required either "Client SSL" or "end to end SSL". Could anyone tell the differenece between these two, so that I can answer to the team?

Comment: It's meaningless. Ask *them* what they're talking about. There are two normal kinds of SSL: server-authenticated and mutually-authenticated. [There is also client-only-authenticated but its usage is vanishingly small.] They might also be talking about HTTPS terminated at a reverse proxy or all the way to the inner server. It's anybody's guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must have understood their question wrong:

- all SSL/TLS for web sites (i.e. HTTPS) is end-to-end
- but you might differ between the cases where only the server has the certificate to identity itself or the client has a certificate too, which can be used to authenticate the client at the server.

Comment: They meant end to end by from browser to so server. By client ssl, they meant between browser to big IP server only

Comment: The existence of an SSL terminating load balancer was the information missing in the question.